# How to retrieve struct (boxed) items from Gee.Map in Vala?

Tags: struct, vala, libgee

I have the following sample code. A Map with (Foo) class items, and a Map with (Bar) struct items:

```
public class Maps {
    Gee.Map<Foo?, int> map1 = new Gee.HashMap<Foo?, int> ();
    Gee.Map<Bar?, int> map2 = new Gee.HashMap<Bar?, int> ();
     
    public Maps () {
        Foo a = new Foo ();
        Foo b = new Foo ();
        Foo c = new Foo ();
        map1.set (a, 1);
        map1.set (b, 2);
        map1.set (c, 3);
        stdout.printf ("Foo = %d %d %d %d\n", map1.get (a), map1.get (b), map1.get (c), map1.size);

        Bar e = Bar ();
        Bar d = Bar ();
        Bar f = Bar ();
        map2.set (d, 1);
        map2.set (e, 2);
        map2.set (f, 3);
        stdout.printf ("Bar = %d %d %d %d\n", map2.get (d), map2.get (e), map2.get (f), map2.size);
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public string name;
    public Foo () {
        name = "foo";
    }
}

public struct Bar {
    public string name;
    public Bar () {
        name = "bar";
    }
}

public static int main (string[] args) {
    stdout.printf ("Start\n");
    var a = new Maps ();
    stdout.printf ("End\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Start
Foo = 1 2 3 3
Bar = 0 0 0 3
End
```

What is it that I am doing wrong as to not being able to retrieve values from map2?

Answer (score 0):

After trolling through the GNOME source, I found the following solution (from Geary):

i.e. Adding custom hash and equal functions.

```
    Gee.Map<Bar?, int> map2 = new Gee.HashMap<Bar?, int> (bar_hash_func, bar_equal_func);

    public static uint bar_hash_func (Bar? n) {
        return hash_memory ((uint8 *) n, sizeof(Bar));
    }

    public static bool bar_equal_func (Bar? a, Bar? b) {
        Bar *bia = (Bar *) a;
        Bar *bib = (Bar *) b;
        return (*bia) == (*bib);
    }

    /**
     * A rotating-XOR hash that can be used to hash memory buffers of any size.
     */
    public static uint hash_memory (void *ptr, size_t bytes) {
        if (ptr == null || bytes == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint8 *u8 = (uint8 *) ptr;
        // initialize hash to first byte value and then rotate-XOR from there
        uint hash = *u8;
        for (int ctr = 1; ctr < bytes; ctr++) {
            hash = (hash << 4) ^ (hash >> 28) ^ (*u8++);
        }
        return hash;
    }
```

Comment: As a side issue, I tried to write these functions using a generic type <T>, but I could not get it to compile properly. I got error: too few arguments to function ‘maps_key_equal_func’ despite using key_equal_func<float>